# Frame drag of event horizons

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, frame-dragging

I was having a discussion with a friend and he brought up that you could float into an event horizon and not know that you had gone in. I believed this only works with a Schwarzschild black hole. He specified a very very large black hole with a large Event Horizon. My contention was that frame drag will not allow anything to enter an event horizon that has not been reduced to the most basic components. Just looking for commentary or equations that would be appropriate. Please don't leave an equation in the dark. I am old and trying to expand my horizons... pun intended. Any help would be appreciated.

It's ok. I solved it. If you leave this up I will come back to put in the answer.

Comment: Why would frame dragging reduce anything to its most basic components?

Comment: Frame dragging is present only in Kerr geometry that arises due to the $g_{t\phi}$ term in the metric. In Schwarzschild geometry there is no frame dragging.

Comment: Jason, I assume that you are asking about massive black holes with spin. If so, you should make that explicit in your question. FWIW, large black holes tend to have a *lot* of spin, as shown in the diagram at the end of this [answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20292/16685) on the Astronomy site.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is correct, locally nothing particularly special happens when you cross an event horizon.* In fact, there is no local observation you could make that can tell you whether or not you are crossing an event horizon. Of course, as you get closer to the black hole, tidal effects will increase (gravity is pulling differently on on end of an object then on the other side). However, tidal effects will always stay finite at the horizon (also when the black hole is rotating). Moreover, the strength of the tidal effects at the horizon is smaller for bigger black holes. Hence, you can't even tell from the size of the tidal effects.

*At least as long as we stick to classical general relativity. Quantum effects could change this (and some people argue that they should).

Comment: Do you have a source for the statement ' nothing particularly special happens when you cross an event horizon'? I am curious.

Comment: @Greg.Paul, Try pretty much any textbook on general relativity.

Comment: Are the people who argue that quantum effects are important at the horizon the same ones who insist that nothing ever falls through the horizon?

Comment: @D.Halsey, No typically they are not. There are fairly reasonable arguments, that suggest quantum things may happen at the horizon.

Comment: OK, I'm glad I didn't start ranting then :)

Comment: *Some* quantum things are happening near the event horizon if Hawking radiation is real. Hawking used a semi-classical approximation, but presumably a full quantum gravity theory will validate Hawking's results.

Comment: @PM2Ring The derivation of Hawking radiation is based on an asymptotic analysis of the spacetime, and is based on what an asymptotic observer would see. We cannot automatically infer that anything is happenning locally at the horizon for a free falling observer. (I agree that Hawking radiation is a hint that something quantum *may* happen at the horizon.)

Comment: @safesphere If you have an answer to the question, please post it as an answer rather than a comment on someone else's answer.

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris, you are a good man! My comment wasn't to answer this question, but to point out that this answer was incorrect. I quoted a published peer reviewed paper in support, but in response received a rude personal attack violating the code of conduct that is a pattern with this user. If this site wants to remain civil, educational, and scientific, personal attacks should not be tolerated and should lead to an immediate suspension. In fact, I am pretty sure the code of conduct already has this provision. Thanks again!

Comment: What exactly does "locally" mean in this context? Does anything happen when your feet are through the event horizon but your head isn't, or if part of your body is further into the black hole than the rest?

Comment: @ikrase "locally" here specifically excludes measurements you could do if you have a sphere or ring that encloses the black hole. This would allow for example the detection of a "trapped surface" signalling the presence of an event horizon. But as long as you are sufficiently smaller than the black hole your feet and head will be part of the same local neighbourhood and nothing particularly special happens to them.